# Class template works in gcc and msvc but not in clang

Tags: c++, aggregate, language-lawyer, c++20

I learnt about class templates in C++ using the book C++ Primer by Stanley. Then I wrote the following program that surprisingly compiles with gcc but not with clang. And I don't know why this is the case. That is, which compiler is correct here in C++20. I have also read about undefined behavior but I'm not sure if this program has that behavior or not.

```
template <typename T>
struct test
{
    T y;
};  

int main()
{
    test t{1};   //compiles with gcc and msvc but not with clang!  
}
```

So can someone tell me what is the correct behavior according to the C++20 standard.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fKWKcG9zE)

Comment: Looks like a clang bug (it cannot compile [examples](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2) H and I from the relevant section of the standard either).

Comment: @StoryTeller-Unslander Monica The dupe is wrong(for this question). There is no parenthesis used in this example by OP unlike the incorrect dupe target. The problem is related to *aggregate deduction guide(candidate)* as described [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696136/12002570).

Answer (score 5):

The program is **well-formed** in C++20 because there is an *aggregate deduction guide(candidate)* `template<typename T> test(T) -> test<T>;` that will be **implicitly generated/considered** for deduction of the template parameter `T` and as a result `T` should be deduced to `int` in your example in C++20 onwards.

This feature was introduced in [P1816R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1816r0.pdf) and clang has not yet implemented it as can be seen from the below given table:

| C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC | Clang | MSVC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class template argument deduction for aggregates | P1816R0 | 10 |  | 19.27* |

As we can see in the above table, there is not entry for clang in the corresponding row which means that this has not yet been implemented in clang while both gcc and msvc support this from version 10 and 19.27 respectively.

---

##### Solution

To make this work with clang, you can explicitly add the deduction guide as shown below:

```
template <typename T>
struct test
{
    T y;
};  
//use this deduction guide
template<typename T> test(T) -> test<T>;
int main()
{
    test t{1};   now works with all compilers
}
```